# Strengthening internal rotation / Subscapularis

Tags: shoulders, rehabilitation, shoulder-cuff, functional-strength

What are the most effective ways of strengthening the Subscapularis muscle?

I know most places on the internet say this isn't necessary, because apparently the subscap is always too strong and often overpowering the external rotators... but this isn't the case with myself.

Also bear in mind I've been getting back into the gym lately, and standard upper body compound exercises haven't strengthened it because my chest and lats etc just take over.

I've tried internal rotation exercises with resistance bands or light dumbbells, but again I can feel my chest and lats getting worked a lot.

I've also tried the 'belly press' exercise with a PT gave me a while ago. This seems a good way to target the subscap, but I'd like something with more resistance and not just an isometric exercise.

Is it even possible to properly isolate the subscap? I've read that this is very difficult

Comment: What exactly makes you think you have a problem with your subscapularis? Do you have a reason to believe that it is weak, or is it just that you don't "feel" it, or that you feel other muscles working, when trying to target it?

Comment: Also, why would you want to strengthen your subscapularis, specifically? Are you competing in arm-wrestling?

Comment: I've had a few PTs in the past tell me that it was very weak after doing the 'liftoff test', I can also test it myself and can tell the right side is a lot weaker than the left. One of them gave me the bellypress exercise which helps a bit, as I can feel it helps to correct some stability issues with overhead movements. But I feel it will take more than just that exercise to make it as strong as my left subscap

Comment: PTs are not 100% correct all the time, the problem may well be elsewhere. Just because you don't "feel" the subscapularis, doesn't mean it's not being strengthened in upper body exercises. Just to satisfy your curiosity, [this](https://exrx.net/WeightExercises/Subscapularis/LVUprightInternalRotation) exercise should feel less in pecs/lats since they are in an elongated position. Although I have to say that it's not great for the shoulder as it can cause impingement.